# How do I get my Google+ page to show up in available employers?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

I've a Google+ business page that's been around for a while and now want to add it to my employment list in my own profile. When I edit employment and type the page name though it doesn't show up in the list.

What do I need to do to get the page recognised here?

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think it matters. When adding an entry in the employment list that has and doesn't have a G+ page, the entries are presented identically. There's no link to the page. I think it's just a convenience to encourage consistent spelling, and I'll bet it only shows pages with a minimum number of followers.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with Google+ page. It merely checks for any existing "employers" (that are used in employment section)

Comment: Like on Facebook?

Comment: This question doesn't show any search/research effort, by the other hand, it's an old question and things relatated to Google+ changed a lot since it was posted, like the UI and the available features. See [Google Plus Platform Realease Notes](https://developers.google.com/+/web/release-notes)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do anything because Google+ doesn't provide this feature.

How do I know this?
I've researched the profile of some famous and normal people and couldn't find a single person that linked their employer's name with the page.